# SetTimeout for fetch() doesn`t work in Mozilla and Safari

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fetch, settimeout, mozilla

I need to set timeout for fetch in react, everything looks good in Google Chrome (timeout is working as expected), but in Firefox and Safari it doesn't work. 
I see just ordinary fetch with no timeout in Mozilla, no errors, just no 15 sec limit.

I have function timeout and use it in fetch. How can i fix my bug? I need to set 15 sec limit in any browzer. Why it does'`t work in Firefox and Safari?

Part of my code is below

```
function timeout (value, promise) {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      reject(new Error('Sorry, request timed out.'));
    }, value)
    promise.then(resolve, reject)
  })
}
return function (dispatch) {
  dispatch(requestConfig())
  return timeout((15*1000), fetch('/config/local?standards=', {
    credentials: "include",
  }))
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(json => {
    const {
      // some code = json
    }
  }) 
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('ERROR:' + err)
    dispatch(catchErrorFetch())
  })
}
```

I expect catching error ('Sorry, request timed out.') after 15 second in any browser

Comment: What behaviour do you see when it does not work? (Please update the question with symptoms.)

Comment: "How can i fix my bug?" ...what's the bug? All you said is it "doesn't work". What is the actual behaviour you're seeing? An error, or unexpected result?

Comment: You would be getting `ERROR: timeout` in console as you are handling the error thrown in catch handler and not `Sorry, request timed out.`

Comment: I see just ordinary fetch with no timeout in Mozilla, no errors, just no 15 sec limit)

Comment: A minimal example of this same code: `timeout = (t) => new Promise((_, reject) => window.setTimeout(_ => reject(new Error('timeout')), t)); Promise.race([timeout(15000), fetch('https://stackoverflow.com/')]).then(...)`.  This works fine from what I can see, maybe check the surrounding code.